# What are the binding sites (or receptors) of cortisol?

Tags: proteins, homework, muscles

I am in the process of a OCR GCSE Case Study, and my question is "Do the benefits of anabolic steroids outweigh the risks, which has an obvious conclusion. 
I need to know the scientific name, or a scientific analysis of why it causes an increase in protein synthesis,  for the binding of cortisol to understand this quote:"Anabolic steroids may block the binding of cortisol to its receptor sites, which would prevent muscle breakdown and enhances recovery.". For without enough understanding i can't explain it.

Comment: might be nice to know what OCR GCSE - would be a good change/update to question

Comment: **Homework questions** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). What research have you done so far to answer this on your own? What have you found out, and where exactly are you stuck? This is not a forum or tutorial site, we [expect](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you to have done previous research on your own. Google searches and Wikipedia are excellent places to start, as is [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query.fcgi?db=PubMed).

Answer (score 2):

The intracellular receptor for cortisol is called NR3C1.
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04150

To my knowledge, a direct (competitive) effect of anabolic steroids on the binding of cortisol to NR3C1 has never been proven. The anabolic effects can easily be explained by other targets. A good starting point for further reading might be this review:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22101547